# Wie teile ich mündlich eine E-Mail-Adresse mit?

Tags: spelling, speaking, spoken-language

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
> *[How to pronounce email address in German?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25306/how-to-pronounce-email-address-in-german)*

Recht häufig muss ich am Telefon eine E-Mail-Adresse mitteilen. Im direkten Gespräch schreibe ich die Adresse meist auf einen Zettel, um Fehler zu vermeiden. Das geht aber am Telefon nicht.

Nehmen wir folgende fiktive Adressen:

## `hans-2233@example.com`

## `hans_mueller@example.org`

Es besteht nicht nur bei mir, sondern oft auch beim Gegenüber Unsicherheit bei folgenden Komponenten der Adressen:

## @

Ist es unmissverständlich, wenn man "ät" für ["@"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-Zeichen) sagt, oder nimmt man eher eine andere Bezeichnung?

## – _

Kann man den Bindestrich auch nur als *Strich* bezeichnen? Ist *Unterstrich* eine hinreichend bekannte Bezeichnung?

## Provider

Wird der Provider eher englisch oder eher deutsch ausgesprochen (*Tschimeil* oder *Gemail*)? Kann man z. B. bei `t-online` den Bindestrich als bekannt voraussetzen und ihn daher weglassen?

## .de .com

Kann man den Punkt vor der Top Level Domain auch weglassen? Falls nein, ist dann *Punkt* oder *Dot* gebräuchlicher? Welche TLD spricht man eher aus, als sie zu buchstabieren?

Comment: Weil ich das nirgendwo sonst beantwortet sehe, aber dafür keine eigene Antwort aufmachen wollte: t-online ist so bekannt, dass man in der Regel nur »Tee onnlain« sagt, und alle verstehen, was gemeint ist. Der Punkt kann auch weggelassen werden, allerdings eher bei sehr bekannten (`t-online.de`, `gmx.de`) und ich würde es nur machen, wenn ihm `de` folgt.

Comment: Das sind viele, unterschiedliche Fragen die unabhängig voneinander beantwortet werden können und müssen. Wer eine gute Antwort für die eine hat muss keine gute für die andere haben.

Comment: @userunknown: nö

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wenn ich am Telefon eine E-Mail-Adresse weitergebe, dann gehe ich wie folgt vor:

## @

Ich sage eigentlich immer 'ät'. Wenn mein Gegenüber das aber nicht versteht (was sehr selten vorkommt), dann greife ich auf '[Klammeraffe](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Klammeraffe)' zurück. Wenn auch das nicht verstanden wird, dann erkläre ich, dass es sich um das Symbol auf der 'Q'-Taste handelt.
<sub>**Anmerkung:**

Das @-Zeichen liegt je nach Betriebsystem und Herkunftsland des Anwenders auf unterschiedlichen Tasten der Tastatur. Mehr dazu steht im ersten Kommentar zu dieser Antwort.</sub>

## – _

Ich nehme eigentlich immer 'Bindestrich' und 'Unterstrich' her. Das wird eigentlich immer verstanden. Früher habe ich nur 'Strich' gesagt, wurde dabei aber oft gefragt, um welche Art es sich jetzt handelt (Bindestrich oder Unterstrich). Für Bindestrich habe ich auch oft 'Minus' gehört.

## Provider

Ich nehme immer die 'deutsche' Variante, da es sonst zu Missverständnissen kommen kann. Wenn Bindestriche vorhanden sind, dann sage ich diese immer, auch wenn es sich um einen bekannten E-Mail-Provider handelt.

## .de .com

Die TLD spreche ich immer aus. Wird dies nicht verstanden, so wird die TLD buchstabiert. Den Punkt lasse ich nicht weg, und ich sage immer 'Punkt', aber ich habe auch oft 'Dot' gehört.

## Allgemein

Generell würde ich immer alles buchstabieren, einfach um etwaige Missverständnisse zu vermeiden.

Comment: **VORSICHT**: Das @-Zeichen befindet sich nur bei deutschen (und österreichischen) Windows-Tastaturen auf dem Q. Jeder, der in D und A einen Computer von Apple hat (so wie ich) findet das @ auf den L. Auf Schweizer Tastaturen (deutsch, aber ohne »ß«) liegt das @ bei Windows auf der Ziffer 2 und bei Apple auf dem G. Auf einem englischen Keyboard liegt @ auch auf 2 (bei Windows und Apple). Wer einen Linux-Rechner benutzt, hat meist eine Windows-Tatstatur und findet das @ wie bei Windows beschrieben.

Answer (score 7):

Meine Meinungen:

- "ät" ist am meisten verbreitet, dann kommt "Klammeraffe"
- Strich halte ich für ungeeignet, weil die Rückfrage bestimmt kommt; erstaunlich verbreitet ist die Aussprache "minus"; zu Unterstrich sehe ich (von "underscore" abgesehen) keine wirkliche Alternative
- außer englische Fragmente wie "online" oder "mail" oder "free" fände ich das komisch
- *nicht* als Buchstabierung begegnen mir nur die klassischen TLDs, also .com, .edu, .gov, .net, und .org, sowie das neuere .info. Und sicherlich "Punkt".

Comment: "Bodenstrich" würde ich eher benutzen als "Unterstrich", ist jedoch eine Frage des Geschmacks sowie der Gewohnheit. Da wo ich herkomme hört man nur "Bodenstrich" für dieses Zeichen...

Comment: @WayneEra: Danke für den Hinweis; begegnet ist mir das noch nie.

Comment: @WayneEra: Und wo kommst Du her? Bodenstrich habe ich noch nie gehört (Herkunft: Trier, Wohnort: Berlin).

Comment: @userunknown Schweiz

Answer (score 5):

Bei vielen Aspekten dieser Frage kommt es auf den Adressaten an. Gegenüber internetunerfahrenen Leuten würde ich den Bindestrich bei t-online dazusagen, usw.

"**ät**" ist ziemlich üblich und wird von den Meisten verstanden.
**Strich** wird inzwischen relativ eindeutig als Bindestrich identifiziert, Minus noch eindeutiger, aber letztlich ist es missverständlich.
Englische und deutsche Aussprache des **Provider**s sehe ich gleichermaßen oft.
"**Punkt**" ist üblicher als "Dot".
Den Punkt würde ich nur gegenüber eindeutig internetaffinen Leuten weglassen.
Länder-**TLDs** werden eigentlich alle buchstabiert, sonstige (.com, .net, .org) ausgesprochen, neue (.sport usw) auch, wenn sie mal vorkommen.
*(Korrigiert auf Basis der Kommentare)*

Comment: Also, wenn ich tatsächlich *Minus* in einer E-Mail-Adresse nutze, kommt die wahrscheinlich nicht an. Die meisten Leute verstehen das zwar richtig, aber man muss ja nicht weiter zu der Unsitte beitragen, den Bindestrich mit einem Minuszeichen zu verwechseln.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Du hast größtenteils, aber nicht ganz recht. Das hier ist ein richtiges Minus: »−« (Unicode U+2212), und das ist kein erlaubtes Zeichen in einer E-Mail-Adresse. Mit normalen Programmen kann man E-Mails gar nicht abschicken, wenn dieses Sonderzeichen in einer Adresse steht. Damit hast du also vollkommen recht. Aber dieses Zeichen: »-« (Unicode U+002D), das auf jeder Computertastatur zu finden ist, heißt ganz offiziell »Bindestrich-Minus«. Typographisch ist es weder ein echtes Minus noch ein echter Bindestrich, sondern ein Hybrid aus ca. ein halbes Dutzend verschiedener Striche.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Naja, U+002D tut in allen praktischen Aspekten genau das, was ein Bindestrich tun sollte, und wird auch selbst in offiziellen Unicode-Veröffentlichungen für den Bindestrich genutzt – der Gedanke, dass man das Zeichen zugunsten zweier anderer aufgibt war utopisch (wenn er denn überhaupt jemals ernsthaft getätigt wurde) und es wird vermutlich auch nie passieren.

Comment: Fuer den ueberfaelligen Kommentar, dass es auf den Adressaten ankommt, +1

Answer (score 4):

hans-2233@example.com
I say

hans "minus" 2233 "ät" example "Punkt" com

hans_mueller@example.org
I say

hans "Unterstrich" mueller "ät" example "Punkt" org

Comment: welcome to german.stackexchange! The question is not so much a forum question "I do this and that, what do you do in that situation", but it asks about different alternatives and their relative merits. So you might want to add some explanation why you think your way of doing it is clearer than other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

[Ich habe die Domains auf example.com bzw. org geändert. Existierende Domains mit potentiell gültigen Adressen zu verwenden kann zu Problemen führen, dafür gibt es ja die Beispieldomains.]

Zur Frage: Ich buchstabiere prinzipiell zunächst den ersten Teil (local part) der Adresse, gefolgt von "ät" für @, dann die Domain, Punkt, com (oder org, de, at, was auch immer.) Strich oder Bindestrich sind (hier) synonym (auch "Minus" habe ich schon gehört), Unterstrich ist ebenfalls gängig. Als bekannt würde ich hier nichts voraussetzen, in dem Fall dann eben "ät t strich online punkt de."